# how to find common in inline styles?

Tags: javascript, styles, compare

I have an array of sequential dom element nodes which may or may not have inline styles.  I need to end up with an object or array with only keys and values common to all the nodes.  Needs to work in IE8+, chrome and FF.

I can't even get one nodes styles into an array without a bunch of other stuff being included as well.

I've tried to use node[x].style but it seems to return a lot of extraneous stuff and other problems.

```
//g is node array
s=[];
for(k in g)
  {
  if(g.hasOwnProperty(k) && g[k]) s[k]=g[k];
  }
console.log(s);
```

gives me `["font-weight", cssText: "font-weight: bold;", fontWeight: "bold"]` which is close but I only want fontWeight: "bold" in the array.  In any case, this only works in chrome.

The only idea I have at the moment that might work is using the cssText and splitting on semi-colons and splitting again on colons but that seems an ugly and slow way to do it especially as I then need to compare to a bunch of nodes and do the same to their styles.

So, I'm hoping someone can come up with a simple elegant solution to the problem posed in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want ONLY styles that are specified inline in the HTML for the object, then you will have to deal with text of the `style` attribute as you surmised.

The `.style` property will show you more styles than were specified on the object itself (showing you default values for some styles) so you can't use that.

Here's a function that takes a collection of DOM nodes and returns a map of common styles (styles that are specified inline and are the same property and value on every object):

```
function getCommonStyles(elems) {
    var styles, styleItem, styleCollection = {}, commonStyles = {}, prop, val;
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var styleText = elems[i].getAttribute("style");
        if (styleText) {
            // split into an array of individual style strings
            styles = styleText.split(/\s*;\s*/);
            for (var j = 0; j < styles.length; j++) {
                // split into the two pieces of a style
                styleItem = styles[j].split(/\s*:\s*/);
                // only if we found exactly two pieces should we count this one
                if (styleItem.length === 2) {
                    prop = styleItem[0];
                    val = styleItem[1];
                    // if we already have this style property in our collection
                    if (styleCollection[prop]) {
                        // if same value, then increment the cntr
                        if (styleCollection[prop].value === val) {
                            ++styleCollection[prop].cntr;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // style tag didn't exist so add it
                        var newTag = {};
                        newTag.value = val;
                        newTag.cntr = 1;
                        styleCollection[prop] = newTag;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // now go through the styleCollection and put the ones in the common styles
    // that were present for every element
    for (var prop in styleCollection) {
        if (styleCollection[prop].cntr === elems.length) {
            commonStyles[prop] = styleCollection[prop].value;
        }
    }
    return(commonStyles);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JW7CZ/

Comment: Awesome! Does what I need.